# I have button and label in stacklayout ,in that when button is click i want to set label.maxline =20 , from view model on button command click

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image]   xaml file content ,i want to set label.maxline on button click command from view model ,but 
    how to access label in view model .

```
                     <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,1" 
                         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                         BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Label x:Name="contentEditor"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           TextColor="Black"
                           MaxLines="3"
                           LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                           Text="{Binding plainContent}"
                           IsVisible="true" />                   

                      <Button  x:Name="btnExpandnCollapse"
                               Text="{Binding moreBtnText}"
                               TextColor="Blue" 
                               IsVisible="{Binding isStopVisible}"
                               HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                               BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                               HeightRequest="{Binding HeightRequest}"
                               Command="{Binding ExpandCommand}"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

In Viewmodel , and also change text of button when its getting click .

```
 public int MaxLines {
        get => _maxLines;
        set => SetProperty(ref  _maxLines, value); }
 public string moreBtnText {                                        
        get => _moreBtnText;                                        
        set => SetProperty(ref _moreBtnText, value);                                                                                                            
 public void OnClick()
    {
       if (MaxLines == 3)
        {
            MaxLines = 20;
            isLabelVisible = true;
            moreBtnText = "less";

        }
        else
        {
            MaxLines = 3;
            moreBtnText = "more";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel you can have a property of the type int and set it 3. You can see as follows:-

ViewModel:-

```
    int _maxLines = 3; //
    public string MaxLines { get => _maxLines; set => SetProperty(ref _maxLines, value); }
```

And

```
public void OnClick()
    {
       if (MaxLines == 3)
        {
            MaxLines = 20;
            isLabelVisible = true;
            moreBtnText = "less";
            plainContent = "";
            plainContent = "Set the full content again so that it reloads.";
        }
        else
        {
            MaxLines = 3;
            moreBtnText = "more";
            plainContent = "";
            plainContent = "Set the full content again so that it reloads.";
        }
```

And the xaml :-

```
<Label x:Name="contentEditor"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           TextColor="Black"
                           MaxLines="{Binding MaxLines}"
                           LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                           Text="{Binding plainContent}"
                           IsVisible="true" />
```

With these changes you the code should work properly.
Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Can you share your viewModel code ? Also, change the public string MaxLines to public int MaxLines. That was a miss by me, sorry for this.

Comment: Does the debug hit the code properly ? Also I think you need to call the plainContent again. See updated post

Comment: plain content is coming from service ,its not static data

Comment: So as H Datronik Suggested, try changing the LineBreakMode as well when the Button is clicked. For this you can make another Property in ViewModel of the type LineBreakMode and Bind it to LineBreakMode.

Answer (score 0):

To get it working, you have to bind the MaxLines property to the Label, just as Nikhil said. How is the plainContent property look like? Is that showing the right text? And if so, is the text long enough to expand to 3+ lines? The MaxLines property on Label is just setting the MAX number of lines, not that it will be 20 lines.

EDIT: The LineBreakMode is set to TailTruncation, which means when a new line is "in place" the text will truncate, so it will never reach a new line, so you have to remove/change the LineBreakMode to make it work.

Example:

```
<Label x:Name="contentEditor"
       Grid.Row="2"
       FontSize="Medium"
       TextColor="Black"
       MaxLines="{Binding ContentEditorMaxLines}"
       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
       Text="{Binding plainContent}"
       IsVisible="true">
    <Label.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ContentEditorMaxLines}" Value="20" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="LineBreakMode" Value="WordWrap" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

Note that I changed the MaxLines property to ContentEditorMaxLines.
And in the ExpandCommand:

```
ContentEditorMaxLines = ContentEditorMaxLines == 3 ? 20 : 3;
```

Comment: @H Datronik i want to show full text when click on button ,and plain content is ssages ,if plain content is more than 3 lines then at first linebreak mode is set to tail trancate when click on more button it will expand.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you have and what you want but I edited my answer with a solution that will expand your text if necessary and change the LineBreakMode.

Comment: @H Datronik i had added accourding to your code but i dont know why my Ui is not getting trigger ,label is not expanded

Comment: Are you sure all your Properties is named correctly everywhere? You should start properties with capital letters (PlainContent instead of plainContent). Does your command trigger and change ContentEditorMaxLines? And is your viewmodel correctly implemented with PropertyChanged?

Comment: @H Datronik  command is triggered but ContentEditorMaxLines is not change.and all property names are correctly added.